# How to subset by group with dplyr

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follows:

```
col1 col2 
1    26  
1    43    
1    34   
2    54
2    27
3    15
4    1
4    4
```

I would like to select only those groups where col2 is more than 25 so the resulting dataset should be

```
  col1 col2 
    1    26  
    1    43    
    1    34   
    2    54
    2    27
```

This is an example dataset rather than the real thing so rather than a simple subset answer I am really looking for a dplyr answer along the lines of:

```
Nr<-Mrd %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  slice(which.min(col2>25))
```

however this answer will get me the rows in each group that are >25 rather than the groups that have >25 as their minimum.

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. In none of your groups the minimum value is larger than 25. Are you looking for *any* value greater than 25? Something like `Mrd %>% group_by(col1) %>%filter(any(col2 > 25))`? You really need to try explaining yourself correctly

Comment: Do you mean that you want to keep `col1` where there is at least 1 value > 25 in `col2`? (i.e. in base r `ind <- df$col1[df$col2 > 25];df[df$col1 %in% ind,]`

Comment: Apologies. I've changed the data so that the minimum in the first two groups is more than 25. The question remains the same however- I want to get the groups where the minimum is greater than 25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your train of thought, you don't need `which.min`, but `min` and `filter` instead of `slice`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(col1) %>% 
   filter(min(col2) > 25)

#Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
#Groups: col1 [2]

#   col1  col2
#  <int> <int>
#1     1    26
#2     1    43
#3     1    34
#4     2    54
#5     2    27
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(min(col2) > 25) .SD, by = col1]
#   col1 col2
#1:    1   26
#2:    1   43
#3:    1   34
#4:    2   54
#5:    2   27
```

---

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(col2>25, col1, FUN = all)),]
#  col1 col2
#1    1   26
#2    1   43
#3    1   34
#4    2   54
#5    2   27
```